# How to trigger click event in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular8

Trying to trigger click event in typescript but not working.
I have one table. Inside table have one div. Initially table data is not loading properly. After doing manually click event on the table the table data is coming. So how to trigger the click event in the table in typescript.

app.component.html:

```
<sdk-table [data]="tableData">

<div id="content"></div>

</sdk-table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit(){

         let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content') as HTMLElement;
         element.click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular (click) event:

```
<sdk-table [data]="tableData">

<div id="content" (click)="onclick()"></div>

</sdk-table>
```

You can also use an event listener on the element in ngOnInit for a more declarative approach.

Edit: [link to relevant doc](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-events)

Comment: Please do not use click event